# Can't ls in /etc directory and more

Tags: command-line, updates, software-center

I am using 14.04, I recently did an update with the software updater and things went wrong.  Not sure what however, I just kept running it until it said that things were up to date.

Now things are very weird.  Now it seems that most things I run from the GUI works fine,  I can surf the web (and post to askubuntu)  I can play music, watch videos..  etc. although the software center is crashing. And the software updater it nowhere to be found now.

I have rebooted several times.

But almost anything I do from the terminal fails, and the terminal closes. Things I can't do from the terminal:

1. I can `cd` to `/etc`, but when I `ls`,  the terminal closes.  (ls does work in most directories, but not all, and I can't tell why)
2. I can't run `maven`.  (I run  `mvn clean`) and terminal closes
3. I can't run `java`  (but `java -version` works)  so weird.
4. `apt-get update` crashes

and a bunch of other things.

I assume I am looking at a re-install here. Can I just do an upgrade of Ubuntu, WITHOUT having to re-install.  I do have all my work on a separate  partition (`/opt`) so I would like to not touch that.

Any pointers?

**UPDATE:**

I am getting this error in Muon Update Manager:

```
Couldn't create temporary file to work with /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_Release - 
mkstemp (13: Permission denied)
```

I am also noticing that I cannot download attachments and stuff from FF.

It almost seems like I am not logged in as who I think I am.  Why would I not have permission for FF to write to my own Download folder?

Comment: What went wrong with the software-updater(can you recall)? Also any error message while doing `ls /etc`?

Comment: I don't recall.  It just said it stopped functioning.  And there are no errors,  the terminal just closes.

Comment: Open `tail -f /var/log/syslog` in a terminal and do `ls /etc` from a separate terminal, now as the second terminal closes check the `syslog` and add the relevant entries to your original question.

Comment: I can tail -f, but when I open a new terminal and run ls /etc  both terminals close.  I open a new terminal, and tail -f,  and nothing new is in the syslog

Comment: Try the console then, press `<ALT> + <CTL> + <F2>` and then try `ls /etc` and other commands.

Comment: Everything worked fine.  mvn, java, ls  all of it..  What is happening?

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-terminal` from console and then try doing stuffs from the `terminal` (not console) (Do `<ALT>+<CTL>+>F7>` to return to graphical interface).

Comment: I was able to reinstall gnome-terminal, but then I cam back to gnome (<alt>+<CTL>+<f7>) then <CTL>+<ALT>+t  and did the ls /etc  it still crashed

Comment: Go back to console and do `less /var/log/syslog` and check for any clue at the occurrence time.

Comment: Nothing is added to the syslog when the terminal crashes.  What I don't get, is that I went to ALT-CTL-F7  and started up oracle, and weblogic,  big apps,  and they all run just fine. It's just gnome I guess.  Is there a way to re-install all gnome stuff?

Comment: Then try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: It seemed to finish...  "setting up ubuntu-desktop (1.325)" and then stops.  I re-boot, but ls /etc still crashes

Comment: For the future: Please read: [What's a good back-up strategy for 1 desktop PC?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)  That way, you just restore your system back-up to a previous state (You're definitely user type 4), apply updates, done!  No need to install your applications again!

Comment: OP reinstalled the latest OS and leaves a note to the _kids_ in the answer section, I'm voting to close the question

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to 14.10 and that fixed it.

Remember kids:  it's always a good idea to partition your HDD and keep your stuff off the root partition.  That way, when you reinstall,  you just re-mount your partition, and everything was like it was.  (except for apps, users, etc..)  But at least I still have my data!

Comment: For the future: Please read: [What's a good back-up strategy for 1 desktop PC?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)  That way, you just restore your system back-up to a previous state (You're definitely user type 4), apply updates, done!  No need to install your applications again!